# Shell script for parsing log file

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script to parse through log file and pull out all instances where sudo succeeded and/or failed. I'm realizing now that this probably would've been easier with shell's equivalent of regex, but I didn't want to take the time to dig around (and now I'm paying the price). Anyway:

```
sudobool=0
sudoCount=0

for i in `cat /var/log/auth.log`;
do
    for word in $i;
    do
        if $word == "sudo:"
        then
            echo "sudo found"
            sudobool=1;
            sudoCount=`expr $sudoCount + 1`;
        fi
    done

    sudobool=0;

done


echo "There were " $sudoCount " attempts to use sudo, " $sudoFailCount " of which failed."
```

So, my understanding of the code I've written: read auth.log and split it up line by line, which are stored in i. Each word in i is checked to see if it is sudo:, if it is, we flip the bool and increment. Once we've finished parsing the line, reset the bool and move to the next line.

However, judging by my output, the shell is trying to execute the individual words of the log file, typically returning '$word : not found'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message arises from a lack of syntax in your `if` statement: you need to put the condition in [[brackets]]

Using the pattern matching in bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudoCount=0
while read line; do
    sudoBool=0
    if [[ "$line" = *sudo:* ]]; then
        sudoBool=1
        (( sudoCount++ ))
        # do something with sudobool ?
    fi
done < /var/log/auth.log
echo "There were $sudoCount attempts to use sudo."
```

I'm not initimately familiar with the auth.log -- what is the pattern to determine success or failure?

Answer (score 4):

why don't you use grep for this?

```
grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

if you want a count pipe it to wc -l

```
grep sudo /var/log/auth.log | wc -l
```

or still better use -c option to grep, which prints how many lines were found containing sudo

```
grep -c sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

or maybe I am missing something simple here?
EDIT: I saw $sudoFailCount after scrolling, do you want to count how many failed attempts were made to use sudo ?? You have not defined any value for $sudoFailCount in your script, so it will print nothing. Also you are missing the `test` brackets `[[ ]]` around your if condition checking

Comment: All great additions to my knowledge base. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Sudhi's answer, here's a one-liner:

```
$ echo "There were $(grep -c ' sudo: ' /var/log/auth.log) attempts to use sudo, $(grep -c ' sudo: .*authentication failure' /var/log/auth.log) of which failed."
There were 17 attempts to use sudo, 1 of which failed.
```